Prompt to commit + push before exiting Visual Studio
Anyone got a way of prompting if you exit Visual Studio (2022) and you haven't done a commit+push?
Just to clarify, I'm not after a solution for Visual Studio Code, and I'm not after something that auto commits/pushes at set intervals, that would pollute the history.
